# Extract data from DB using scanner value

Tags: java, database, jdbc, java.util.scanner

i'd like some help in regards of this code i wrote.

The idea is to enter a username 'nomU' (xx, for example) in the scanner and using this username, the program will search in my database and bring me all the 'pref' that are associated to this username from a table named 'usermodel'.

```
try {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Veuillez saisir un mot :");
    String str = sc.nextLine();

    Statement stmt2 = null;
    String query2 = "SELECT pref FROM usermodel  WHERE nomU =" + str + "";
    stmt2 = connexion.createStatement();
    ResultSet resultat2 = stmt2.executeQuery(query2);
    while (resultat2.next()) {
        String pref = (String) resultat2.getString("pref");
        System.out.println("l' element , " + pref + ",est une préférence de l'utilisateur " + str + " .");
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
}
```

here is what the table "usermodel" looks like

```
id     nomU     pref
-------------------------
1       xx      adblock
-------------------------
2       yy      grammarly
-------------------------
3       xx      avast
------------------------
```

so the result for nomU= xx is supposed to be (adblock and avast)
but it is not working ,when i enter the username nothing happens,
i have to point out that the connection and everything works perfectely.

I'de appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String should be between `'str'`, but i don't suggest to use this way this can cause Syntax error or SQL Injection instead you have to use PreparedStatement:

```
String query = "SELECT pref FROM usermodel  WHERE nomU = ?";

try (PreparedStatement prstm = connection.prepareStatement(query)){

    prstm.setSting(str);//set your input the query

    ResultSet resultat2 = prstm.executeQuery(query2);
    while (resultat2.next()) {
        String pref = (String) resultat2.getString("pref");
        System.out.println("l' element , " + pref + ",est une préférence de l'utilisateur " + str + " .");
    }
}
```